# Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a'

Tags: list, haskell, types, list-comprehension

I have the following function which should adds up all numbers in a given list up to the current position. For example, `subtotal [1, 2, 3, 4] = [1, 3, 6, 10]`, because 1 = 1, 1 + 2 = 3, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 and 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

Here's my code:

```
subtotal :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
subtotal [] = []
subtotal xs = [y | n <- [1..length xs], y <- sum(take n xs)]
```

The problem is Im getting this error:

```
cw.hs:3:46: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          subtotal :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> [a]
        at cw.hs:1:1-31
    * In the expression: sum (take n xs)
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: y <- sum (take n xs)
      In the expression:
        [y | n <- [1 .. length xs], y <- sum (take n xs)]
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at cw.hs:3:10)
        subtotal :: [a] -> [a] (bound at cw.hs:2:1)
  |
3 | subtotal xs = [y | n <- [1..length xs], y <- sum(take n xs)]
  |                                              ^^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: just put brackets around the `sum(take n xs)` as in `y <- [sum(take n xs)]`, and you're golden. see also [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.3C-),  [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.2C) and [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7C).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sum(take n xs)` is **not a list**, so you can not iterate over it. In order to add the result of an expression to a list you **put the expression in the head of the list comprehension**:

```
subtotal :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
subtotal xs = [sum (take n xs) | n <- [1..length xs]]
```

But you here use `length`. `length` is a bit a dangerous function since lists can be infinite, and then your function will simply keep looping, and never return an element. You can use `inits` however to obtain all the lists:

```
Prelude Data.List> inits [1,4,2,5]
[[],[1],[1,4],[1,4,2],[1,4,2,5]]
```

So you can use:

```
import Data.List(inits)

subtotal :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
subtotal xs = [sum sub | sub <- tail (inits xs)]
```

But this is still not very effectively: now we calculate the sum of every sublist. But a problem here is that we calculate the sum of every list separately. This is weird since the sum of the *i*-th result is simply the sum of the *i-1*-th result plus the *i*-th element of `xs`. We can use `scanl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`:

```
subtotal :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
subtotal xs = scanl1 (+) xs
```

or even more simple and elegant:

```
subtotal :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
subtotal = scanl1 (+)
```

Answer (score 5):

In a list comprehension, the statement `y <- ys` means that `ys` is a list and `y` iterates over the elements of that list. So `y <- sum (take n xs)` means that `sum` produces a list and you iterate over that list. But `sum` only produces a single number, not a list; so you get an error.

You want to use `let` instead of `<-` to assign simple expressions:

```
subtotal xs = [y | n <- [1..length xs], let y = sum(take n xs)]
```

Or just put the expression directly into the head of the comprehension:

```
subtotal xs = [sum (take n xs) | n <- [1..length xs]]
```

PS: Your first case (for the empty list) is redundant. It's just a special case of the second.